# Error while creating hive table

Tags: hive

I used the following syntax while creating the hive table--

```
Create table tablename (ColumnName Type) 
row format SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
with SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = "\;")
lines terminated by '\n'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count" = "1");
```

But I am getting an error message

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:361 missing EOF at 'lines' near ')'

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single column, you don't need a separatorchar.If you have multiple fields and if they are separated by `';'` then you don't need to escape the `';'`

```
SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ";")
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/path/yourfile.csv'
```